# Taking out perfect square

Tags: scheme

How would you write a code that will remove the perfect squares from a list, using only filter and integer? which I believe is built in scheme. For example. (take-out-perfect-squares '(1 2 9 16 5 64)) should return (2 5) because the square root of everything else in that list returns an integer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (take-out-perfect-squares l)
  (cond ((null? l) '())
        ((integer? (sqrt (car l)))
         (take-out-perfect-squares (cdr l)))
        (else
         (cons (car l) (take-out-perfect-squares (cdr l))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define remove-perfect-square-helper
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (null? x)
        (reverse y)
    (if (integer? (sqrt (car x)))
        (remove-perfect-square-helper (cdr x) y)
        (remove-perfect-square-helper (cdr x) (cons (car x) y))))))

(define remove-perfect-square
        (lambda (x)
          (remove-perfect-square-helper x '())))


(define x '(1 2 9 16 5 64))

(remove-perfect-square x)
```